# How to create a button on the interface that shows the values ​of a patch variable in NetLogo version 6.2?

Tags: netlogo

I have a beginner question: I would like to create a button in interface to show the values of patch variable (patches-own: resource). I would like to click once to show the patch variable (resource) and to click the button again to make the patch variable disappear. And I want also do this with colors, if this variable is less than 0.2, it will be gray and not green. That is:

1. I have a patch-own variable that is called resource. This variable varies for example from 0 to 1. I want all patches that have the value <=0.2 to be gray and the rest green

So, I would like to create a button on the NetLogo 6.2 interface that when clicking on it would appear:

1. the green and gray patches (gray when the values ​​of the resources variable were <=0.2)
2. the resource variable values ​​of each patch (for example: patch (0,0) has a reource value of 0.2, the patch (0, 1) has a resource value of 0.9

After clicking again on the same button it would disappear

Is it possible to do that?

My code:

```
ask patches [
ifelse plabel = "" [

set plabel  (word "(" resource ")") ;;Here, I would like to show the resource value of ;each patch
set plabel-color white 
  ] 
  [ 
  set plabel ""
  ]


no-display
ask patches [
    ;; low values 
    ifelse resource  <= 0.2 [ set pcolor gray + 4 ]  [
    set pcolor green - 4 ] ;; high value
  ]
display
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to make sure I understood well... you want a button that: [1] if you click once, it makes every patch show its value of `resource` as a patch-label AND ALSO changing the patches' colours; [2] if you click another time, it shows every patch coordinates as a patch-label (is this correct? and if it is correct, do you want this to show together with the `resource` value? That seems a lot for a label); [3] if you click it another time, all the labels and `resource`-related `pcolors` disappear.

Is this exactly what you're looking to do?

Comment: In part, you got it right. But, I messed up my question. I tried to edit it to make it more understandable. Did it get better? Thanks for attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a global variable that controls the state of display, and let the effect of the button adjust accordingly by using `ifelse`.

For example:

```
; The name of the button is "display-resource"

globals [
 display-control 
]

patches-own [
 resource 
]

to setup
  clear-all
  ask patches [
   set resource precision (random-float 1) (1)
  ]
end

to display-resource
  ifelse (display-control = 0)
   [display-on]
   [display-off]
end

to display-on
  ask patches [
   ;set plabel resource
   ifelse (resource <= 0.2)
    [set pcolor grey]
    [set pcolor green - 1] 
  ]
  
  set display-control 1
end

to display-off
  ask patches [
   ;set plabel ""
   set pcolor black 
  ]
  
  set display-control 0
end
```

Some things to note:

- Note that I included the part about adding `plabel`, but I commented it out. Up to you to choose, but having every patch displaying a number as `plabel` will make the view very packed of symbols. This is the case even if `resource` (or its displayed value) goes only as far as the first decimal place - which is what `set resource precision (random-float 1) (1)` does.
- If you still want to get more information from this display mode ("more" referring to the fact that you might give up using `plabel`), you can consider using [scale-color](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#scale-color) which will give a more nuanced colouring.
- I don't know which would be the previous state of patches' colours, so I just put `set pcolor black` in my case to go to the previous state.